# How do you recurse directories, unzip, and move everything up?

Tags: command-line, find, unzip

Say I have the following directory tree

```
.
├── a1
│   └── sub1
│       └── a1.zip
└── a2
    └── sub2
        └── a2.zip
```

The current directory contains `a1` and `a2` directories. I want to recursively search, locate and extract all zip files, and move everything up to `a1` and `a2` respectively. The goal state is:

```
.
├── a1
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
└── a2
    ├── file1
    └── file2
```

Where the files came from the zip. How do I accomplish that? What tools should I use in Terminal for that?

**EDIT**

To be more specific, I mention the recursion since we don't know how many subdirectories there are. It could be:

```
.
├── a1
│   └── sub1
│       └── sub...
│                └── a1.zip
│                └── text1.txt
└── a2
    └── sub2
        └── sub...
                 └── a2.zip
                 └── text2.txt
```

Goal:

```
.
├── a1
│   ├── file1_unzipped
│   └── text1.txt
└── a2
    ├── file1_unzipped
    └── text2.txt
```

Comment: yes, move everything

Comment: Please, take a look at the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51841035/2457251 if you want more insights. For example, you can add the command `mv $f` to the .sh file - or add any other command, if you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Unzip all `.zip` archives

```
find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} +
```

#### Explanations

- `find .` – search current directory for
- `-type f` – files
- `-name "*.zip"` – whose name match `*.zip` (so ends in `.zip`),
- `-exec unzip {} +` – make one long list of all matches and and run `unzip` on it

### 2. Move all files from lower levels to one level under the current

```
for i in */; do find "$i" -type f -exec mv {} "$i" \; && rm -r "$i"*/; done
```

#### Explanations

- `for i in */; do …; done` – loop over all directories on the current level
- `find "$i" -type f` – search all files in the currently processed directory and below
- `-exec mv {} "$i" \;` – move them to the currently processed directory
- `&&` do the following only if the previous command finished successfully
- `rm -r "$i"*/` – remove every subdirectory in the currently processed directory

Comment: Actually, the subdirectories have subdirectories themselves, hence the recursion. An optimal solution would use `find` once for `a1`, extract the `.zip` in the same location it is located, and move everything in that location up to `a1`. Then repeat the same for `a2`. How would I do that?